# Proper ASP String Concatenation for ASP Classic

Tags: asp-classic

Im having an issue getting a string properly formatted for a SQL command I have three variables which are set:

```
Dim pastMonth, currentMonth, futureMonth
currentMonth = Month(Date())
pastMonth = currentMonth-1
futureMonth = currentMonth+1
```

and the string im trying to setup is:

```
strSQL="SELECT * FROM Project WHERE P_MONTH BETWEEN " & pastMonth &" AND " & futureMonth
```

based on other resources it appears that the & symbol is the correct use to concatenate variables, but the error states otherwise:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression.
```

Thoughts? Thank you for your help and assistance.

Comment: I did answer, but then I see you're only comparing the month, not a proper date. Is the month being stored in the DB as an integer?

Comment: Great question Martin, in this particular instance im setting up "views" to sort particular information which is in the form of a drop down menu, so users can pick string values "new" "held" as well as assign the record to the particular month. With this mix I thought the most approprate way would be to use string values. Unless there would be better way to do this?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think most data types can be concatenated into sql using apostrophes. For example, an integer can be put into an sql statement like this:  `...'" & intValue & "'...`, the same as  `...'" & strValue & "'...`and  `...'" & dateValue & "'...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using the ampersand is the way to concatenate strings.

It may be that dates require apostrophes, like this:

```
strSQL="SELECT * FROM Project WHERE P_MONTH BETWEEN '" & pastMonth &"' AND '" & futureMonth & "'"
```

But I'd strongly recommend that you change approach and use a parameterized query to perform this operation.

I use code like the following in classic asp:

```
public function select_rst(sql, parameterArray)
    dim cnx, cmd, i
    Set cnx=CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cnx.Open wfDataConnection       
    Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    With cmd    
        .CommandText = sql
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        .ActiveConnection = cnx 
        if isArray(parameterArray) then             
            for each i in parameterArray
                .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(i(0), i(1), i(2), i(3), i(4))
            next
        end if
    end with
    Set select_rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    With select_rst
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .Open cmd
        Set .ActiveConnection = Nothing
    End With            
    Set cmd = Nothing
    cnx.close
    set cnx=nothing     
end function
```

Calling it like so:

```
dim sql, parameterArray
sql = "SELECT * FROM Project WHERE P_MONTH BETWEEN ? AND ?"
parameterArray = Array(_
                     Array("@p1", adInteger, adParamInput, , pastMonth)_
                    , Array("@p2", adInteger, adParamInput, , futureMonth)_
                 )

set rst = select_rst(sql, parameterArray)

    '....do stuff with rst...

set rst = nothing
```

I'm not too sure about the variable names (@p1, @p2, etc) when creating parameters. It doesn't seem to matter what you call the variables, but they do require some kind of name in order for it to work.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, and thank you for your additional insight into creating a parameterized query! I will begin to implement this method as soon as I conduct additional testing with my existing code.

Comment: This approach does require you to know the data type of the parameter - adInteger, adDbTimestamp, adVarChar, etc.